# List of dictionaries in jinja

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I want to iterate through a list of dictionaries using jinja.

here is my list :

```
[{'product': 'EC2', 'cost': 3.5145240400000013}, {'product': 'ElastiCache', 'cost': 1.632000000000001}, {'product': 'Elasticsearch', 'cost': 4.423768260000001}, {'product': 'RDS', 'cost': 1.632000000000001}]
```

My template :

```
{% for dict_item in products %}
   {% for product, cost in dict_item.items() %}
          <h1>Product: {{ product }}</h1>
          <h2>Cost: {{ cost }}</h2>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And finally the output :

```
<h1>Product: product</h1>
<h2>Cost: EC2</h2>

<h1>Product: cost</h1>
<h2>Cost: 3.51452404</h2>



<h1>Product: product</h1>
<h2>Cost: ElastiCache</h2>

<h1>Product: cost</h1>
<h2>Cost: 1.632</h2>



<h1>Product: product</h1>
<h2>Cost: Elasticsearch</h2>

<h1>Product: cost</h1>
<h2>Cost: 4.42376826</h2>



<h1>Product: product</h1>
<h2>Cost: RDS</h2>

<h1>Product: cost</h1>
<h2>Cost: 1.632</h2>
```

As you can see there is something wrong with that output. All the data are mixed up and I don't get why.

I just want something like :

```
<h1>Product: EC2</h1>
<h2>Cost: 3.5145240400000013</h2>
```

Comment: Just do `<h1>Product: {{ dict_item.product }}</h1>` and `<h2>Cost: {{ dict_item.cost }}</h2>`. No need for another loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:-

```
{% for dict_item in products %}
          <h1>Product: {{ dict_item['product'] }}</h1>
          <h2>Cost: {{ dict_item['cost'] }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```